# Integration of fraction (substition?)

Tags: integration

How to integrate the fraction $\frac{1+t}{t^2-1}$? Is there a substitution involved? I do not see how to solve this step. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\require{cancel}\frac{1+t}{t^2-1}=\frac{\cancel{(t+1)}}{\cancel{(t+1)}(t-1)}=\frac1{t-1}\qquad\color{grey}\forall\, t\neq\pm1$$

which can be easily integrated using a $u$-substitution.

I hope this helps. 
Best wishes, $\mathcal H$akim.

Comment: minor correction, you meant $t\ne \color{red}{-}1$

Comment: @Sabyasachi True, but $1$ should also be excluded

Comment: Thanks, corrected. $\overset{\cdot\cdot}\smile$

Comment: @imranfat ah you're right ofcourse. If anything $-1$ is a removable singularity and doesn't *need* to be excluded. Removing $1$ is more important. You're right.

Comment: How are you creating that slash with tex? Sorry off topic, but just curious.

Comment: Dear @RyanMcGaha , I create that slash by first introducing in my Tex code: `\require{cancel}` only then I can use `\cancel{whatever}` to slash. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1+t}{t^2-1}=\frac{1}{t-1}\text{ for } t\ne-1$$

Answer (score -1):

Note that $t^2-1=(t-1)(t+1)$. Now cancel the common term $t+1$ from the numerator and denominator. You will be left with $1/(t-1)$ which is easy to integrate.